# Accordion keeping the panel open on a postback with jquery

Tags: jquery

I have the following example of a accordion.

http://jsfiddle.net/zidski/NU7Gp/14/

If you click down on the first panel and you should see a edit put - once you click the edit button the panel closes - I'll trying to keep this panel open when you have a postback - how can this be achieved with jquery?

Comment: don't reload, reloading will make you lose the status of the page

Comment: you have a `window.location.reload` in the click event of that button. What did you expect?

Comment: I have a asp.net ajax call which reloads the html but I need to keep the panel open

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to do the postback using AJAX.  As in:

```
$('#myFormId').submit(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    $.post($(this).attr('action'), function(response){
        // ... handle response from post here ...
    });
});
```

Right now you're just reloading the page as one comment suggests.  I'm assuming you were doing that to simulate a form post back.  Basically, think about it like this.  A page is "born" when you first load it.  If you reload in any way, you "kill" that page, and all javascript state and setup that was done.  The only way to keep that state is to keep the page "alive" by using asynchronous requests and DOM manipulation.  Good luck, welcome to the web :)